# What are the ways to run a android activity in different process

Tags: android, process

What are the ways to starts a android activity in different process .

one I know is Adding in the manifest

```
android:process=":YourProcessName">
```

is there any other method while starting Activity using intent etc?

Comment: You can only run one Activity at once... Do you mean Service?

Comment: No, I just want to know though we start activity once, I want to know different methods to starts in new process

Comment: Threads? AsyncTask? Are you trying to run a whole Activity, or just a method?

Comment: I want to start a whole activity which has some UI component

Answer (score 1):

> is there any other method while starting Activity using intent etc?

No, sorry.

Note that running activities in separate processes is usually unnecessary.